# How to put access time limit on a php

Tags: php, time, limit

I am trying to put limit on a PHP script. For example in `index.php` user enters some code/password and is redirected to `content.php`
there he can use my script lets say `final.php`.

I want something like this that after using my script, if he want to use it again. He need to wait for 5 minutes or so.

I.e. user must not be able to get access to `final.php` (from `content.php`) and instead he must get an error saying please wait 5 minutes.

I am new to PHP so please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how `content.php` will look like -

```
<?php 
session_start();
include('final.php');
?>
```

here's hows `final.php` will look like :-

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start();
$currentTime=round(microtime(true));
$UserRegTime=(isset($_SESSION["last_access_time"]))?$_SESSION["last_access_time"]:'0';
if(($currentTime-$UserRegTime)>300)
{
//Write ACCESS Content Code Here
echo "Granted";
$_SESSION['last_access_time']=$currentTime;
}
else
{
echo "Please Wait For ".(300-($currentTime-$UserRegTime))." Seconds To Gain Access";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

I would advice you to save a record for each usage per user with a timestamp. In case the interval with timestamp and NOW is smaller than 5 minutes, generate the error.

You can save these records in several ways:

- A session per user
- A database record for each usage with a reference to the user
- Et cetera

Since the question is very generic, I can't provide you with any examples. In case you don't know how to approach something like this, I would advice you to Google some example in using the technologies above. In case you come across a concrete question, feel free to open up a new question on Stackoverflow so we can provide you with a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SESSION`. When user will go to the final.php first time, you should save current timestamp to the `$_SESSION` variable and next time you will check if the difference between this variable and current timestamp is more then 5 minutes